# Prove that the set of linear maps is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So, please tell me if my idea is correct. Can I use the this switch? If no, then how to prove it?

1. Commutativity
   $\left(T_1+T_2\right  (v)=\left(T_2+T_1\right)(v)$

Proof:
$w=Tv$
$\left(T_1+T_2\right)(v)=T_1 v+T_2 v=w_1+w_2=w_2+w_1= T_2 v+T_1 v =\left(T_2+T_1\right) (v)$

4. Additive inverse
   $\forall T \in L(V, W): \exists S \in L(V: W):(T+S)(v)=0 v$

Proof:
$Tv= w, $
$Sv=-w$
$(T+S)(v)=Tv+Sv=w-w=0_W=0 v$

Comment: Hard to see what you wish to prove. A set of maps is not a map. Do you mean some particular set of linear maps is to be proved to be a vector space? If so you need to define your particular set of maps, for one thing.

Comment: You mean …. Is a vector space? The set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$ is indeed a vector space, typically denoted $L(V,W)$ or $\text{Hom}(V,W)$.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I mean a Vector space

Comment: Sure, so are you checking all the properties of a vector space or just those few?

Comment: I check them all, just post these two to know if I do it correct

Comment: I think the short answer is no, your idea is not well enough expressed to consider this a valid proof of "the set of linear maps is a vector space."  You should use the body of the Question to give a complete problem statement.  Don't rely on the title alone to setup the problem, give all the setup and context in the body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ over a field $K$ and consider the set $L(V,W)$ of all linear maps $V \to W$.
I am assuming you want to show that $L(V,W)$ is a vector space with the following structure:
$$ + : L(V,W) \times L(V,W) \to L(V,W)$$
$$ (T_1,T_2) \mapsto [v \mapsto T_1(v) + T_2(v)]$$
$$ \cdot : K \times L(V,W) \to L(V,W)$$
$$ (k,T) \mapsto [v \mapsto k \cdot T(v)]$$
and the identity element for $+$ is the zero map $0_{L(V,W)}$ (the maps that sends every element of $V$ to $0_W$)
(Your notation for the maps is not totally clear. $w = Tv$ doesn't define a map).

**For commutative property**: Let $T_1,T_2 \in L(V,W)$ and fix any element $v \in V$. Then $$(T_1 + T_2)(v) = T_1(v) + T_2(v)$$ by definition. Now, $T_1(v)$ and $T_2(v)$ are both element of $W$ and, since $W$ is a vector space, the addition in $W$ is commutative. Thus
$$T_1(v) + T_2(v) = T_2(v) + T_1(v) $$
By definition, $T_2(v) + T_1(v) = (T_2 + T_1)(v)$. We just proved that, for any $v \in V$, $(T_1 + T_2)(v) = (T_2 + T_1)(v)$. Since two function are equal if their output are equal for every input, we proved that $T_1 + T_2 = T_2 + T_1$. Since this holds for every $T_1,T_2 \in L(V,W)$, we have that $+$ is commutative in $L(V,W)$.

**For additive inverses**: you need to show that, for every $T \in L(V,W)$, there exists $S \in L(V,W)$ such that $T + S = 0_{L(V,W)}$. Thus, fix $T \in L(V,W)$ and define a function $S$ as follows: for every $v \in V$, $S(v) = -T(v)$. This makes sense since, being $W$ a vector space and being $T(v) \in W$, there exists an additive inverse of $T(v)$ that we denote by $-T(v)$. You should show that $S$, as defined above, is a linear map (hence $S \in L(V,W)$) and $T + S = 0_{L(V,W)}$ i.e. for every $v \in V$, we want $(T+S)(v) = 0_{L(V,W)}(v) = 0_W $. You can check that the above claims are both true.

(*Note*: This is not enough to prove that it is a vector space.)